# Recommended Calendar app for Salesforce?

Tags: appexchange, calendar

Our goal is to provide the sales team more visibility into our production team's calendar. I have heard great things about Asana's Calendar, but it seems like Zapier is needed to integrate the two apps, which I am not a fan of.

Does the SE Salesforce community have any preferred/recommended calendar apps specifically tailored to production/project management scheduling?

Comment: Are you looking for any specific features? ans it is not supported in standard SFDC calendar? I see multi user calendar view in SFDC is good.